# Biblatex problem with brackets in textcite citations using authoryear-comp style in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, brackets

I have this code for the bibliography in my Latex document.

```
   \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb} 
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[italian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage[
           backend=biber,
           bibstyle=authoryear,
           citestyle=authoryear-comp,
           natbib=true,
           firstinits=true,
           uniquename=init,
           uniquelist=false,
           uniquename=full,
           uniquelist=true,
           dashed=false,
           hyperref=true,
           maxcitenames=4,
           maxbibnames=99,
           language=italian,
    %           autocite=inline,          
    %           sortcites=true,
    %           labeldate=true
    ]{biblatex}  

\bibliography{./biblatex/tesi2015.bib}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citeblue}{RGB}{46,48,146}  
\definecolor{linkblue}{RGB}{0,51,153}   
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduzione}

\textcites{mcclymont2008characterization}{mcclymont2008visualization}{mcclymont2009fault}{mcclymont2010shallow}

\defbibfilter{allbooks}{
  type=book or
  type=inbook
}

\printbibheading[title={Bibliography},heading=bibliography]
\printbibliography[filter=allbooks,heading=subbibliography,title={Book References}]
\printbibliography[nottype=book,nottype=inbook,heading=subbibliography,title={Papers}]


\end{document}
```

When I do multiple citation like this:

```
\textcites{mcclymont2008characterization}{mcclymont2008visualization}{mcclymont2009fault}{mcclymont2010shallow}
```

Or this:

```
\textcite{mcclymont2008characterization, mcclymont2008visualization, mcclymont2009fault, mcclymont2010shallow}
```

I should obtain

McClymont et al. (2008a, 2008b, 2009, 2010).

But what I see in the text is this citation:

[image]

Without parenthesis in the latest three years.

Can someone help me? I'm trying to solve this problem since three days :D

This is the .bib entry:

```
@article{mcclymont2008visualization,
  title={Visualization of active faults using geometric attributes of 3D GPR data: An example from the Alpine Fault Zone, New Zealand},
  author={McClymont, Alastair F and Green, Alan G and Streich, Rita and Horstmeyer, Heinrich and Tronicke, Jens and Nobes, David C and Pettinga, Jarg and Campbell, Jocelyn and Langridge, Robert},
  journal={Geophysics},
  volume={73},
  number={2},
  pages={B11--B23},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Society of Exploration Geophysicists}
}

@article{mcclymont2010shallow,
  title={Shallow fault segmentation of the Alpine fault zone, New Zealand revealed from 2-and 3-D GPR surveying},
  author={McClymont, Alastair F and Green, Alan G and Kaiser, Anna and Horstmeyer, Heinrich and Langridge, Robert},
  journal={Journal of Applied Geophysics},
  volume={70},
  number={4},
  pages={343--354},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{mcclymont2008characterization,
  title={Characterization of the shallow structures of active fault zones using 3-D ground-penetrating radar data},
  author={McClymont, Alastair F and Green, Alan G and Villamor, Pilar and Horstmeyer, Heinrich and Grass, Christof and Nobes, David C},
  journal={Journal of Geophysical Research: Solid Earth (1978--2012)},
  volume={113},
  number={B10},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{mcclymont2009fault,
  title={Fault displacement accumulation and slip rate variability within the Taupo Rift (New Zealand) based on trench and 3-D ground-penetrating radar data},
  author={McClymont, Alastair F and Villamor, Pilar and Green, Alan G},
  journal={Tectonics},
  volume={28},
  number={4},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

Comment: `\textcites` (with an `s`)?

Comment: create a _complete_ example which shows the behaviour. With the biblatex example bib and an up-to-date TL2015 I get with `\textcites`the output `Aristotle (1907, 1929, 1968)`

Comment: You can use \textcite{key1,key2,key3} or \textcites{key1}{key2}{key3} in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct. You have three different authors which will printed as three different cites:

[image]

only for identical authors you'll get something like `foo et al (1008, 2009)`

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought that with the same first-author name I would have got a unique citation with different years in any case.